# SQL count of non primary ID based on most recent date

Tags: sql, date, count

I have a scenario where i need to take Distinct count of the ID based on the latest date.

```
ID              OccurredOn
1717          2017-07-21 08:56:01.553
1719          2017-07-21 08:42:21.377
1719          2017-07-04 08:51:49.827
1719          2017-07-04 08:51:11.670
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: What RDBMS (MySQL, SQL-Server, etc...) are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..                                                                          Using SQL SERVER.. Actually I need the Count of the ID..  Expected Result would be..                                                                                                                                                IDCount             
2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want max date per ID so you could use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` in following:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(OccuredOn) AS OccuredOn
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID
```

So output will be like:

```
ID            OccurredOn
1717          2017-07-21 08:56:01.553
1719          2017-07-04 08:51:49.827
```

Another thinking if you want to get count of ID per latest day in SQL-Server you  could try something like:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(OccuredOn) AS OccuredOn, MAX(cnt) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, CAST(OccuredOn AS DATE) ORDER BY OccuredOn ASC) AS cnt, 
        CAST(OccuredOn AS DATE)AS OccuredOn
    FROM tbl
)x
GROUP BY ID
```

So output will be:

```
ID      OccuredOn   cnt
1717    2017-07-21  1
1719    2017-07-21  1
```

**UPDATE**

In subquery you could datetime column convert to date, take max date per each ID. After it select count of each distinct ID. Try in following:

```
SELECT COUNT(OccuredOn) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        MAX(CAST(OccuredOn AS DATE)) AS OccuredOn
    FROM #t
    GROUP BY ID
)x
```

Comment: Expected Result would be..                                                                                                                                                IDCount             
2

Comment: @user2030293 `Select count(distinct id) as IDCount;` will return 2.

Comment: No.. I have used this query 
SELECT count(distinct ID), MAX(OccuredOn) AS OccuredOn
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID.. But my output is                                                       
 Count occuredOn
1 2017-07-21 08:56:01.553
1 2017-07-21 08:42:21.377 I dont want like this..  the query should return 2

Comment: My query will return exactly one row with  exactly one column equal to 2 as per your requirement. Why No?

Comment: @user2030293 edit your question and provide more details, I can't understand what you want. As in your question: `Distinct count of the ID based on the latest date.` what the hell is this...?

Comment: Unable to edit my question.. My expected result would be one single column as "count"  value should be 2, after eliminating old dates in occured on..

Comment: @user2030293 Why it should be count 2? So why it's wrong: `Select count(distinct id) as IDCount` as Serg provided?

Comment: I need overall count of the ID based on latest date.. not each individual ID's count

Comment: Show example data where `Select count(distinct id) as IDCount from myTable` returns 3 but it should be only 2.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas Thank you very much.. this is what i expected..

Comment: @serg sorry man.. I didn't mean to say your query is wrong.. that will return 2 i agree.. It is my mistake, i should have been clear with my question..

Comment: @user2030293  Never mind, it's just sql. Btw the last  Stanislovas query will return exactly the number of different Ids  as direct count(distinct.. ) will do.